# Ter o layout pronto facilita o desenvolvimento com MVC?

Tags: php, html, mvc, layout

Estou aprendendo a programar e estudando dezenas de coisas ao mesmo tempo porque programar é o meu trabalho.

O que eu gostaria de saber é sobre MVC.

Eu imaginei que em relação ao MVC, o V de *view* deveria ter o seu HTML pronto logo ao iniciar o projeto, o que permitiria ter uma melhor compreensão do que se está fazendo.

Será que a minha conclusão está correta e ter o *layout* pronto facilita o desenvolvimento com MVC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acredito que sim. A ideia do MVC é justamente [separar as responsabilidades](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/417198/101) dos diversos componentes e até mesmo as tarefas a serem executadas no projeto.

Mas se considerar que o *layout* nunca está pronto não faz tanta diferença. Cada um pode achar seu melhor modelo de gerenciamento do projeto. Isso pode variar com a quantidade e qualificação específica dos seus membros.

Alguns poderão dizer que todo o *backend* (*model* e *controller*) deve ser feito antes e com a devida especificação disto o responsável por montar o HTML deve construir o *layout* como quiser. Outros preferirão construir o HTML e dali começar especificar o que o *controller* deve fazer e dele definir como deve ser o *model*. As duas abordagens podem produzir resultados melhores e mais produtivos em circunstâncias diferentes.

Experimente os dois e veja qual é o melhor para seu caso, quando tiver experiência, saberá escolher de antemão em cada caso. Obviamente uma solução híbrida é possível.

O que é certo é que precisa dos requisitos primeiro, mesmo que obtidos informalmente. Só não pode ser no *achômetro*, por incrível que pareça, muito software é feito sem isto. Pode ser perigoso fazer o *layout* para achar a especificação, mas há casos que, feito com cuidado, pode ser uma opção válida.