# O que é Separação de Interesses (SoC - Separation of Concerns)?

Tags: engenharia-de-software, projeto-de-software, princípios-de-programação

Notei que não temos uma pergunta sobre este tópico.

Separation of concerns (SoC), também conhecida como:

- Separação de interesses
- Separação de preocupações
- Separação de responsabilidades
- Separação de conceitos

Gostaria de saber:

- O que é?
- Como funciona?
- Como atingi-la?

Opcionalmente, um bom material para se ler a respeito (Dijkstra, etc.)

Comment: Vou ver se consigo fazer algo legal. Essa é uma das coisas que se sabe o que é mas não é fácil definir :) De qualquer forma estudar o que é não ajuda muito a fazer certo a não ser pelo fato que aí não está completamente cego no assunto, como tudo que a gente tem que fazer com sistemas.

Comment: Também encaixa em [tag:design-patterns]?

Comment: Até tu, @JeffersonQuesado. Não é um design pattern, é um princípio.

Comment: @Piovezan por ignorância perguntei, honestamente tenho dificuldades em distinguir os "princípios"

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado É um princípio de design. Não pergunte o que é um, aqui eu faço as perguntas :D

Answer (score 4):

## Introdução

Para entender o que significa a Separação de Responsabilidades, vamos antes ver o que é o primeiro princípio do S.O.L.I.D: *Sigle Responsability Principle* (SRP), ou Princípio da Responsabilidade Única.

### Princípio da Responsabilidade Única

Este princípio diz que, de uma maneira bem simples, uma classe ou módulo de ter uma única responsabilidade, ou podemos dizer que, do que faz o software, tal módulo ou classe é responsável por única “parte”.

Por exemplo, num sistema de consulta de produtos, uma classe que **faz somente a consulta dos dados do produto no banco de dados**, está aderente ao SRP.

É importante entender que, esse princípio visa tornar mais fácil a manutenção e o entendimento do sistema, uma vez que um código tem uma única responsabilidade, é mais fácil saber onde precisa ser alterado para fazer uma certa manutenção ou nova funcionalidade.

## Separação de Responsabilidades

A Separação de Responsabilidades é um princípio/padrão de arquitetura de software que tem o mesmo princípio do SRP, mas com uma visão um pouco mais macro, não a nível de classe, mas de pacote, assembly, etc, que visa separar a aplicação em “partes” que sejam responsáveis por responsabilidades distintas.

Por exemplo, se a tal classe do exemplo acima (vamos chamá-la de *RepositorioProduto* para facilitar), e essa classe está num pacote que contém outra classe (vamos chamá-la de *RepositorioCliente*), que é responsável por consultar os dados do cliente, parece razoável dizer que elas, **dentro das suas funções unitárias**, tem funções semelhantes, que poderíamos dizer que são a de obter informações do banco de dados.

Agora imagine que temos outra classe que **formata dos dados de produto para serem exibidos ao usuário**, e vamos chamá-la de *FormataProduto*. Do ponto de vista do SRP, esta classe está aderente, ela somente faz uma coisa, mas se ela estiver no mesmo pacote, assembly, etc, que a classe *RepositorioProduto*, ela não está aderente à Separação de Responsabilidades, porque uma classe tem uma responsabilidade a nível de repositório de dados, e ou a outra a nível de apresentação ao usuário, por isso eles devem estar separadas.

### Como conseguir? Exemplos

Essa separação pode ser feita de forma lógica ou física, e geralmente é implementada ao se criar layers (camadas) no código.
Temos o modelo clássico Apresentação/Negócio/Repositório, o bem conhecido modelo em **3 camadas**, onde cada pacote, projeto, assembly tem uma responsabilidade.
Dentro desses componentes podemos ter infinitas classes com assuntos em comum, fazendo com que a responsabilidade seja bem definida.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa separação também pode ser feita de maneira lógica, agrupando os componentes dentro do mesmo pacote mas de uma maneira seja fácil identificar.
Isso acontece com projetos que usam o **padrão MVC** (*Model, View, Controller*), que em muitos projetos, apesar da separação das responsabilidades, podem ter os componentes no mesmo pacote, mas separados de forma lógica, em pastas, *namespaces*, etc.

Abaixo um exemplo da separação lógica das responsabilidades de um projeto usando o padrão MVC

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Benefícios

Isso tem vários benefícios, podemos pensar por exemplo:

- Facilidade de entendimento dos componentes: se bem implementada a separação e precisarmos mudar a forma como algo é exibido ao usuário, podemos alterar somente alguma classe da camada de apresentação;
- Ajuda na estimativa de manutenção ou novas funcionalidades: é mais fácil olhar numa parte somente do código e estimar esforço se sabemos bem onde vai ser necessário alterar;
- Desacoplamento: se cada camada tiver sua responsabilidade bem separada, fica mais fácil desacoplar cada uma delas. Aqui duas situações interessantes: podemos alterar e publicar somente um pacote de código no lugar de todo o código se a alteração for numa camada. É possível ainda substituir toda uma camada sem afetar o restante do código dependendo de como ele está implementado. Poderia por exemplo substituir o banco de dados sem ser necessário alterar as outras camadas, ou ainda a camada de apresentação, mudando de uma aplicação Desktop para uma Web por exemplo.

Answer (score 2):

Bom, qualquer pattern se origina de algum problema recorrente e que fora encontrada uma abordagem padrão para sua solução.
Então acredito que mesmo desconhecendo você já utiliza algum nível de SoC sem mesmo saber. 
E quando eu digo nível entendasse, "nível de granularidade aplicada", onde o nível mais baixo de granularidade poderia gerar vários Code Smells
e o nível mais alto poderia ser considerado uma Overengineering. Por isso cabe aos envolvidos no projeto definir qual é o melhor nível a se aplicar e monitorar se o mesmo está sendo seguido.
Lembrando também que SoC não é só pra desenvolvimento BackEnd mas sim na concepção da arquitetura como um todo, e vai desde da definição da arquitetura até a definição de uma entidade.
Vamos ao um exemplo em um menor nível possível de granularidade em uma aplicação web, que a um bom tempo atrás era prática comum em ASP, PHP, Java e as melhorias subsequentes foram pensandas visando SoC.

**Nível 0 - Sem SoC - Tudo junto e misturado**

HTML/Javascript/CSS/Código BackEnd na mesma página html/jsp/php/asp;
Variáveis, regras de negócio, acesso a banco (Abertura de conexão, queries de banco).
**Positivo:** Você sabia que tudo que remetia a uma tela por exemplo, estaria no arquivo da tela
**Negativo:** Sem entidades, classes de serviços, nada, tendo que encontrar regras de negócio definidas dentro de uma , terra sem lei, inferno na terra.

**Nível 1 - MVC - Divisão em camadas lógicas**

View - Tudo que representava a apresentação de dados, como uma página ou um relatório, ainda se via código back end entre HTML, CSS e Javascript
Controller - Definição do fluxo da página, ainda se ve código de banco nessas classes, classes utilitarias pra conexão
Model - Entidades de banco, DTOs, ViewModels, VOs, etc - classes pra amarzenar e trafegar dados
**Positivo:** Um pouco mais organizado
**Negativo:** Nesse modelo ainda se via uso de regra de negócio em todas as camadas

**Nível 2 - BO/DAO**

Nesse modelo houve introdução de classes de negócio (Business Object - BO).
Grandes classes de acesso a banco (Data Acess Object - DAO)
Classes utilitárias de conexão de banco, Log, parse de Data, etc..
**Positivo:** As regras de negócio ficavam separadas do MVC, só sendo utilizadas quando necessário, melhor reaproveitamento de código.
**Negativo:** As classes não tinham uma "única responsabilidade", ou seja, qualquer parte do sistema poderia ser responsável pelo o aumento de uma classe.

**Nível 3 - Services/Repositories**

Melhor separação dos regras de negócio e acesso a dados.
Cada service/repository representa as regras de negócio e definição de acesso a dados de uma tela, feature ou entidade. 
A partir daqui você já ve muito o uso de DI (Denpendency Injection).
S.O.L.I.D. em alta, classes coesas, métodos coesos, váriaveis coesas.
**Positivo:** Uma definição melhor de Single Responsibility, manutenção simplificada, cada classe cresce em função somente do que ela foi criada. 
**Negativo:** Aumento no número de classes, mais trabalho pro GCs se fazendo necessário o uso de DI (Denpendency Injection) pra controlar o live cycle das classes.

**Nível 4 - Separação em camadas físicas**

Separação físicas entre camadas com responsabilidade "únicas" (Ou pelo menos deveriam ser únicas).
Cada camada seria um projeto, assembly, dll, jar, etc.. ligado entre si.
Ex: Web, Test, Bussiness, DAL (Data Acess Layer)
Ex2: Web, Services, Repositories, Domain, Core
**Positivo:** Já não é mais um monolito. Pequenos projetos que podem ser atualizados de forma idependente dependendo da situação, manutenção simplificada.
**Negativo:** Deve se ter cuidado para manter o saneamento dos projetos, manter eles coesos, controle de versionamento.

**Nível 5 - API, Web Services - Front End totalmente apartado do Back End**

Nessa modalidade, você poderia ter uma aplicação Web, uma Mobile, utilizando uma mesma API.
Uso de SOAP, REST, Messageria, e outros recursos de sistema distribuidos.
Aqui agente já fala de Isolate of Concern, aplicações isoladas integradas entre si, para concepção de um produto.
Deve ser respeitar contratos de interfaces para integração se manter coesa.
**Positivo:** Cada um no seu quadrado, ninguém mexe no que não deve mexer, menos código para manter, é mais fácil achar que parte do sistema precisa de mais atenção.
**Negativo:** Basicamente estamos lidando com um aplicação distribuida, ou seja, para formar um unico sistema, se faz necessário várias aplicações, distintas, com versões distintas, deploys distintos, talvez até equipes, se não for feito direito, pode gerar dor de cabeça.

**Nível 6 - Microserviços**

Uma segregação maior de um sistema, envolvendo até segregação de banco.
Cada Microserviço pode ser independente ou não.
Divisão de um único sistema, levando em conta a carga (tem muitos acessos, é mais pesado, trafega mais dados, crítico) ou dominio(referente a um Módulo).
Cada Microserviços tem sua responsabilidade, seu motivo para existir, e cresce em função de suas próprias necessidades.
Cloud, DevOps;
**Positivo:** Cada Microserviço poderia ser mantido por uma equipe pequena, mantendo um contrato nas suas interfaces o Microserviço é facil de manter, mais fácil de testar, pode ser contruído em linguagem/banco indepente, ficando mais fácil de otimizar.
**Negativo:** Apesar do Microserviço ser fácil de manter, a aplicação feita em Microserviços fica extremamente dificil de manter sem DevOps, fazendo necessidade manter os recursos em um orquestrador, Cloud.

**Nível 7 - Servless**

Em vez de segregar por dominio, porque não segregar por função? Cada serviço servless correponde a menor parte executável de uma aplicação.
Essa é a menor responsabilidade mantida até hoje, usar com cautela, em situações propensas.
Uma solução pode ser um monolito e ter um recurso em servless.
Se utilizado corretamente, pode ter uma econmia enorme em certas atividades da aplicação.
Tem outros poréms dessa arquitetura, várias discussões envolvendo ela, mas vou deixar de lado para manter a brevidade.
**Positivo:** Fácil de mjanter o código, escopo menor.
**Negativo:** Pode acarretar custo exagerado se feito incorretamente, deploy dificultado, lentidão pra subir se a aplicação estiver fria, dificuldade.

Em qualquer um desses niveis é possível fazer algo funcional e mantenível, do mesmo jeito que pode ser feito algo insustentavel. E no geral vai depender de como é sua aplicação.

> Fazer uma aplicação em 10, 20 camadas? O sistema nunca vai crescer,
>   pra que separar em camadas? Uma unica feature do seu sistema, está
>   separada em 10 classes de serviços? Tem a necessidade de usar
>   Microserviços? E Servless? Você ta preparado pra gerenciar isso?