# Quais partes de um projeto fazem parte da camada de infraestrutura?

Tags: arquitetura-de-software, organização-de-projeto

O meu objetivo é saber se as classes relacionadas aos tópicos abaixo se encaixam nessa categoria de infraestrutura para separá-las em camadas dentro de um projeto. Seguem os tópicos:

- Banco de dados
- Log
- Container de injeção de dependência (e outras configurações)
- Rotas (controllers e etc)
- Login

Qual dessas partes de um projeto são considerados infraestrutura? Também gostaria de mais exemplos sobre partes de um projeto que são da infraestrutura. Prentendo separar o projeto em namespaces como Infrastructure, por exemplo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você aplica a **arquitetura em camadas** (*layered architecture*) em sua aplicação, então a infraestrutura é uma das camadas lógicas (no sentido de não-físicas), chamada de **camada de infraestrutura** (*infrastructure layer*).

Não se refere à infraestrutura que dá suporte à aplicação como um todo (no sentido de servidor, banco de dados, etc.), em vez disso é uma forma de alcançar [separação de responsabilidades](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/417198/357) no código envolvido na sua aplicação.

Em outras palavras, o banco de dados em si não pertence à camada de infraestrutura (ele nem faz parte da aplicação), porém o código que faz acesso ao banco pertence.

O código que acessa o banco (um DAO ou Repository por exemplo) é considerado parte da camada de infraestrutura, assim como o código que grava log em arquivo ou envia para um servidor, o código que grava/lê dados em arquivos de forma geral (por exemplo, arquivos de configuração), o código que grava mensagens em um serviço de fila de mensagens (*message queue*), etc.

São todos considerados códigos de "suporte" à aplicação e acesso a recursos exteriores (*hardware*), não são referentes à interface com o usuário, nem às regras de negócio (camada de domínio) nem às regras da aplicação (camada de aplicação).

São serviços disponíveis para o código da camada de domínio.

Dentre os tópicos que você citou, já citei banco de dados e log, não sei dizer sobre o container de injeção de dependência, que até hoje não conheço a tecnologia. Controllers de MVC são camada de interface com o usuário, já controllers de back-end e rotas pelo que desconfio que sejam são camada de aplicação.

Login é um caso de uso que passa por todas as camadas, desde interface de usuário passando por camada de aplicação, camada de domínio e acessando o banco via camada de infraestrutura.