# Por que preciso relançar a exceção mesmo depois de tratar ela?

Tags: java, exceção

Em uma explicação de Java de um canal no Youtube diz que precisamos relançar a exceção no `throw e` como se fosse uma nova tentativa de criação do arquivo se algo desse errado no código abaixo, por exemplo uma restrição de criar arquivo no sistema operacional. Eu fiquei mais em dúvida do porquê ele lançou aquele `throw e`.

- Quando ele lança a exceção no `throw e`, ele está lançando o método criar arquivo de novo?
- Por que precisa lançar ela de novo para tentar criar um novo arquivo caso algo de errado?
- E porque quando eu lanço esse `throw e` o método pede para eu declarar na assinatura o `throws IOException` mesmo tratando a exceção com `try` e `catch`?

```
package academy.devdojo.maratona.javacore.Oexception.exception.test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ExceptionTest02 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        criarNovoArquivo();
        System.out.println("Criou arquivo");


    }


    public static void criarNovoArquivo() throws IOException {
        File file = new File("arquivo\\teste.txt");
        try{
            file.createNewFile();

        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
      }


    }

}
```

Comment: No seu caso, não há uma nova tentativa de criar o arquivo. Se `createNewFile` lançar um `IOException`, o `catch` só imprime detalhes da exceção e a relança. E no método `main` não há qualquer tratamento desta exceção. Não dá pra saber se o curso explicou pela metade ou vc que ainda não viu tudo, porque só com isso não dá pra avaliar nada. Aliás, tem certeza que o código é esse mesmo? [**Porque ele nem sequer compila**](https://ideone.com/s30Ux1). Para compilar, o `main` precisaria ter um `try`/`catch` também (ou então ele mesmo ter um `throws`). Enfim...

Comment: E só pra constar que são 2 coisas diferentes: uma é o `try`/`catch`, que pega a exceção que pode ocorrer em `file.createNewFile()`. Outra é o `throws`, que é necessário porque indica que o método pode lançar uma exceção (já que dentro dele tem um `throw`). Basicamente, `throw e` está relançando a mesma exceção que o `catch` capturou. É como se ele só estivesse "passando pra frente".

Comment: E só pra terminar, `createNewFile()` retorna um *boolean* indicando se conseguiu criar o arquivo ou se ele já existia: *Returns: `true` if the named file does not exist and was successfully created; `false` if the named file already exists*, então um código completo verificaria isso pra saber se o arquivo foi de fato criado ou se já existia. A exceção é para verificar se outra situação ocorreu (por exemplo, usuário não tem permissão, disco cheio, etc)

Comment: @hkotsubo se tiver um problema de permissão por exemplo, ele nem retorna nada, a exceção é que é lançada, certo? Em que casos poderia não ter sido criado sem lançar a exceção? ou seja, quando o arquivo não é criado por uma situação não excepcional? Não é esquisito ter as duas situações?

Comment: @Maniero A documentação diz que retorna `false` se já existir um arquivo com o mesmo nome. Então eu entendo que para todos os outros casos, lança exceção

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É bem, simples, não precisa. Isso é um erro muito comum. Alguém fez errado (ou fez certo em algum caso muito específico) e os outros copiaram. Foi de cópia em cópia, até que praticamente virou verdade.

É o mesmo processo de *fake news* de política. Vai se espalhando tanto que fica difícil convencer as pessoas do contrário.

Por isso que tudo, mas tudo mesmo, que você não sabe porque está sendo usado, não use. Aprenda a usar corretamente em todos os sentidos para depois usar. Agora está fazendo o certo, questionou para ver se isso tem necessidade mesmo.

Veja bem, não estou dizendo que isso deveria ser banido da programação, mas é muito raro você ter que fazer isso. Eu nem consigo te dar um exemplo agora onde seria adequado.

Posso te dar um exemplo hipotético em cima de um trecho hipotético, mas ele não deveria contar. O seu código pode ter sido feito para ilustrar apenas. Ele é um caso em que pode ter sido útil sim. Mas só por uma razão, a exceção não foi tratada efetivamente, por isso provavelmente ela terá que ser tratada em outro lugar, aí precisa que ela continue sendo propagada.

Na verdade, não é bem assim, ela lança outra exceção completamente diferente perdendo a informação original de onde ocorreu a exceção, portanto se não é o que queria fazer, e geralmente não é, isso é um erro.

Se não pode fazer nada útil com a exceção não a capture. Simples assim. Só capture para tratar de verdade. Se não pode fazer nada aí, deixe para outro local do código tratar.

Tratar significa que vai resolver a questão ou vai quebrar a aplicação.

Novamente, pode ter um caso que isso não deveria ser feito assim? Claro, pode ter, mas é raro. Você pode justificar porque precisou capturar e só imprimir o *stack trace* sem resolver a questão ou quebrar a aplicação? Se puder, então pode usar.

Tudo em código precisa ser justificado. Voltamos ao começo da resposta.

Programar é entender o que está fazendo e não só jogar códigos quase aleatórios.

Porque ele fez isso é algo que pode perguntar para ele. Pode ser só ilustrativo.

Muitos exemplos que encontramos por aí, até, e principalmente, em documentação são só para mostrar o mecanismo funcionando, não é uma receita de código para copiar e colar. E isso a maioria das pessoas não sabem. Esses códigos mostram como funciona e não qual é a "melhor prática".

É parecido com exemplo de OOP que `Cachorro` herda de `Animal`, onde todo mundo aprende OOP errado porque é um exemplo para ilustrar simbolicamente a herança de um jeito que as pessoas já entendem o mundo, e não como você deve fazer herança em código real.

> Quando ele lança a exceção no "throw e", ele está lançando o método criar arquivo de novo?

Não. Não é possível lançar um método. Ele está lançando uma exceção em um local diferente. Não está criando uma nova exceção, está usando a que já recebeu.

> Por que precisa lançar ela de novo para tentar criar um novo arquivo caso algo de errado?

Não está tentando criar o arquivo de novo. Pode ser a intenção, mas não faz isso em lugar algum. Poderia fazer. Poderia ter criado um *loop* que tente, talvez passando um tempo entre uma tentativa e outra, talvez contando quantas vezes pode retentar.

Eu sempre falo para [capturar a exceção mais específica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21933/101) que pode fazer algo útil. Muita gente é contra isso sei lá porque, talvez só porque outras pessoas também o são. Se você não capturar algo específico não pode dar um bom direcionamento. O que é o mais específico necessário depende de cada caso.

Mais do que retentar a esmo, eu acho que deveria informar o usuário que a tentativa falhou para ele ver se pode fazer algo para resolver. Em grande parte dos casos falhará por algo que não se consertará sozinho.

Pode ser falta de permissão, espaço cheio, o dispositivo quebrou, e mais um monte de coisa. A `IOException` não diz o que é, porque ela não é a mais específica possível. Pode ser que tenha uma mensagem genérica nela que informe, e pelo menos mostrando o *stack trace* ajude, e aí uma nova tentativa seria interessante, mas é feio fazer isso, ter algo mais específico ajuda mais.

Na verdade, você poderia até mesmo interagir com o usuário aí. Mas quase sempre isso seria um erro. Não parece que em um bom código um método que só `criaArquivo()` deveria interagir com o usuário. Em grande parte dos casos você nem sabe se está interagindo com console, alguma GUI específica ou web ou até não ter um usuário para interagir.

Outra parte do código que sabe, deveria interagir. Deveria [separar as responsabilidades](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/417198/101).

> E porque quando eu lanço esse `throw e` o método pede para eu declarar na assinatura o `throws IOException` mesmo tratando a exceção com `try` e `catch`?

- [O que são checked exceptions?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/214768/101)
- [Usando as palavras-chave Throws e Throw](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17025/101)

Uma das maiores desgraças das *checked exceptions* é isso, as pessoas capturam sem motivo para cumprir a exigência da linguagem. Só não capture, deixe que outro lugar capture:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
 
class ExceptionTest02 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            criarNovoArquivo();
            System.out.println("Criou arquivo");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
 
    public static void criarNovoArquivo() throws IOException {
        File file = new File("arquivo\\teste.txt");
        file.createNewFile();
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/EPHqlI). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/wwqlvzvdan-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/IO/Exception.java).

Note que para cumprir a exigência de capturar eu coloquei outro `throws IOException` delegando a responsabilidade para outro método.

Eu poderia fazer o mesmo no `main()` e não precisaria usar o `try-catch` nem nele. Daria no mesmo exceto pelo detalhe que finalizaria com um erro, do jeito que está nesse código termina sem erro.

Eu não estou dizendo para fazer isso, estou capturando ali no final só para cumprir o exigido, o ideal seria fazer algo mais, que ajude resolver o problema, que informe melhor usuário de uma forma agradável, que interaja para tentar resolver. Mas se é pra quebrar depois disso então não é um grande problema, ainda mais em um exemplo para aprendizado.

Veja o comentário acima do hkotsubo sobre ter que verificar se o arquivo já existia, ou seja, além de lidar com a exceção tem que colocar alguma `if` para identificar outro tip ode erro. Conseguiram fazer uma API com o pior dos dois mundos.

## Conclusão

Espero que depois ele mostre uma forma melhor de fazer. Eu sempre torço para cursos serem bons, não ensinem errado. Mas entendo que tem momentos para aprender a ideia básica. Mas como é frequente as pessoas se confundirem como se aquilo fosse o jeito certo de fazer, os cursos deveriam alertar melhor para o fato, talvez dizendo que não está completo.